# CallDirectory Handler extension error while using Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, callkit

I'm using Callkit extension to identify the numbers. All my contacts (around 30k+) are stored in Realm.

I have stored the Realm file in AppGroup which can be shared between my app and its extensions.

I get the error when I try to reload the extension.

> Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager Code=7
>   "(null)"

When this error occurred , the setting for Call Blocking & Identification for my app shows a spinner (while other apps show the switch to toggle)

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance] reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:@"com.j2x.handheldcontact.CallerID" completionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"CallerID - refresh failed. error is %@",[error description]);
        }
    }];
}
```

I see that the error happens only when I try to use access the Realm in the app group directory.

In my extension subclass:

```
- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context
{
    context.delegate = self;

     NSString *appGroupId = @"group.com.j2x.handheldcontact.CallerID";
     NSURL *appGroupDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:appGroupId];

     NSURL *dataBaseURL = [appGroupDirectoryPath  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.realm"];

    [[[RLMRealm defaultRealm]configuration]setFileURL:dataBaseURL];

    RLMResults *temp = [self getContactArray];  //This gives the callKit error
    RLMResults *temp ; //This doesn't give any error

    [context completeRequestWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}


-(RLMResults *)getContactArray{

    RLMResults *res = [[RealmContact allObjects]objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phone <> nil or homePhone <> nil or mobilePhone <> nil or altPhone <> nil or fax <> nil"]];

    return res;

}
```

Why does accessing the Realm data gives the error ? The predicate format does look ok to me.

With some research I found the following code:

```
public enum Code : Int {


        public typealias _ErrorType = CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError

        case unknown

        case noExtensionFound

        case loadingInterrupted

        case entriesOutOfOrder

        case duplicateEntries

        case maximumEntriesExceeded

        case extensionDisabled

        @available(iOS 10.3, *)
        case currentlyLoading

        @available(iOS 11.0, *)
        case unexpectedIncrementalRemoval
    }
```

In my case , the error says case currentlyLoading (code 7). I also tried this on realm with only 250 contacts . But I got the same error.

Edit:

If I hardcode the contact, it works fine. But if I bring Realm into scene, it fails.

```
 CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumber = strtoull([@"14xxxxxx86" UTF8String], NULL, 0);
    if (phoneNumber > 0) {
        [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:@"Test Test"];
    }
```

Workaround:

For now, I'm storing all my data into a file and saving that file in the app group.

```
NSString *appGroupId = @"group.xxx.CallerID";
        NSURL *appGroupDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:appGroupId];
        NSURL *appFile = [appGroupDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.txt"];

        BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[appFile path]];
        if(exists) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:[appFile path] error:nil];
        }

        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:uniqueCallDirectory toFile:[appFile path]];
```

and accessing this array in the callID extension subclass.

Comment: Try to run the same code in your container app.

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri: Did you solve this problem? I also get the error {Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager Code=7 "(null)" but cant figure out why... I can't enable the extension in the phone settings. There is just loading icon which spins endless... thx

Answer (score 0):

The list you provide to `addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber` must be ordered by **ascending phone Number**. Retrieve the list from realm in ascending order. (else it will break and keep the loading icon when you activate the extension)